# Php array format is google api analytics

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my current array : `$stats->rows`

`[["Austria","1","1","1"],["Brazil","5","5","5"],["Italy","4","4","4"]]`

---

**My progress:**

```
$data= count($stats->rows);

$array = array();
for( $i=0 ; $i <= $data-1 ; $i++ ){

 $total= $stats->rows[$i][1] +
 $stats->rows[$i][2] +$stats->rows[$i][3];


 $array[][] = $stats->rows[$i][0].','.$total;

  }
```

**And my Array Output is following:**

`[["Austria,3"],["Brazil,15"],["Italy,12"]]`

---

But I want to following  array   :

`[["Austria",3],["Brazil",15],["Italy",12]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array_map`:

```
$newData = array_map(function($value) {
    return array($value[0], array_sum(array_slice($value, 1)));
}, $stats->rows);
```

To insert a new value at the beginning of the array:

```
array_unshift($newData, array("Country","Enter"));
```

Comment: array_push($newData, ["Country", "Enter"]);  ?  first 0 [ ["Country", "Enter"],["Austria",3],["Brazil",15],["Italy",12]]

Comment: @pull, what do you mean?

Comment: array_push($newData, ["index0", "Enter"]); Your function How can I do ? index 0  [ ["Country", "Enter"],["Austria",3],["Brazil",15],["Italy",12]]

Comment: And I'm still wondering, what are you trying to tell me? The `array_push` you're writing don't make sense to me. Are you having trouble making it work? You want to insert a new array at index 0?

Comment: $newData = array_map(function($value) {
    return  $dump = array($value[0], array_sum(array_slice($value, 1)));
    }, $stats->rows);
    $newData[0] = ["Country", "enter"];

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

*Update*

```
  // from your curent array
 $newarray=array();
 if( count($stats->rows)>0)foreach($stats->rows as $k=>$v){
    $newarray[$k]=array($stats->rows[0],($stats->rows[1]+$stats->rows[2]+$stats->rows[3]));
 }
```